# Select a row by default and send XHR request with jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

I am trying to get first row of my tables selected and send request by ajax based on selected row. So far I can only select my first row but still not able to send request.

## Logic

[image: one]

## Code

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var table = $("#projects_table").DataTable({
    'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex) {
        if (dataIndex == 0) {
            $(row).addClass('selected'); // selected row (first one)
        };
        setTimeout( function () {
            table.draw();
        }, 100 );
    }
});

$('#projects_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    $('.addVisit').hide();
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        var scheduleID = '';
        var projectID = '';
        $('.projectName').empty();
        $('#projectName').empty();
    } else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.projectName').empty();
        $('#projectName').empty();

        var projectID = $(this).data('id'); //this should get data-id of selected row above

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'{{url('dashboard/getProjectVisits')}}/'+projectID, //this should be excuted
            success:function(data){
                // retunting my data in second table and this process repeats
                // for all my tables in this view.
                // (to clear the code i removed this part)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

Here is my tables HTML code

```
<!-- projects table -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h6 class="panel-title">Projects</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="projects_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="projects_table2">
                @foreach($projects as $project)
                <tr data-id="{{$project->id}}">
                    <td>{{$project->name}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- visits table -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h6 class="panel-title"><span class="projectName"></span> Visits</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="schedule_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>From Date</th>
                    <th>To Date</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="schedule_table2"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure request is not sending.?
did you checked in the network Tab .?

Comment: @AmanDeep yes..

Comment: so you mean it's going into the else block, But not executing the ajax code .?

Comment: @AmanDeep yes all i get currently is my first table, first row selected but nothing return in second table i still have to click on selected row in order to get data in second table (i want to avoid that click and data return automatically)

Comment: @AmanDeep any idea?

Comment: Can you add your html code please?

Comment: not sure. really.

Comment: @AliMaleki sure i'll update my question

Comment: just for curiosity, is the html written in laravel or asp.net?

Comment: @VipulDessai laravel

Comment: @mafortis I think adding the laravel tag to the question might be helpful

Comment: @VipulDessai this has nothing to do with laravel yet i add who knows right? :)

Comment: yes, you are correct it's not related to laravel, but ur html has laravel so may be might help :-)

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a Fiddle? Do you have errors in the Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was with triggering the click event after binding click event handler.

Here is a working CodeSandbox reproduction of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/datatables-select-row-by-default-and-send-request-fnpu7

DataTables is now instantiated without `createdRow` handler function in its configuration, and we are using jQuery click trigger after click event binding:

```js
var table = $("#projects_table").DataTable();

// ...

$("#projects_table tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  // ...
});

$("#projects_table tbody tr:first-child").trigger("click");
```

Comment: thanks i will try it and let you know if it works or not

Comment: no it wasn't do anything still not sending id while page loads, same as before i still need to click

Comment: @mafortis I see, so I've just updated that Codesandbox. Can you see my edits there? I've removed `createdRow` handler from DataTables instantiation configuration, and added jQuery click trigger after attaching click event handler: `$("#projects_table tbody tr:first-child").trigger("click");`

Comment: thank man i will test it and let you know, meanwhile let me ask: why using `trigger("click")`? my data are returning by click right now what i'm seeking is to have first row data without any click when page loads. `PS` i haven't test your code yet maybe works as i wish i just ask to get more knowledge.

Comment: I have tested your code, it appears too work IF, I remove `if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) { $(this).removeClass('selected'); }  else {` part otherwise won't work, my concern now is if i remove that if condition from datatables it cause issues in functionalities in future. What do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you are wanting it to work as a user experience. Currently, it is selecting the first row and sends the request after the page is loaded?

Comment: The idea for triggering click event on the first row is that, if you are also doing selected state modifications to the visuality of the row item on the event handler, then you'd execute that code as well. Otherwise, you could extract the request to oa function which takes the project ID as a parameter, and execute that function in both the click event handler and outside of the handler.

Comment: @mafortis if my answer solves your question, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: sure, today is working day i will put final test on it and let you know. i still concern about removing datatables default if condition in order to make it work.